# Fixed dimension for android app

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am trying to create an android application will support 3d sbs(side by side) mode.A normal 1080ps TV have a resolution of 1920 X 1080 px.If we turn on the 3D mode the resolution will change,I think the width increased by 100 px each side and this will make a slight border on each side.To avoid this problem i was trying to render more pixel than the actual resolution.I was created a web application with two side and the app devided at the central portion and render two identical views.and i called the url in a webview.Here is the layout,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="2120px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Code

```
setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.2.200/app/out/");
```

Here the design view shows like my requirement but when i run my app ,it only output 1920 X 1080 resolution output.

Before using android a was try is it possible with cordova,but i can't find any solution.

For more details : [Fixed dimension for cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294121/fixed-dimension-for-cordova-app)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

<WebView android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: sorry,Actually i need to output like in the image  i added in the image.3d mode require more pixel in width each side