# Set app width and height manually android or cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I was searching find a solution for creating my app for android device.I need to set the app width and height manually and the app should vertically aligned on center.Is there any way to create an apk using any of the technology like android,cordova etc  ?

[image]

I have asked some questions  before some days almost same requirement,and i unable to find a solution for those issues.

Here is the links that contains examples i have tried,

[Fixed dimension for android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406611/fixed-dimension-for-android-app)

[Fixed dimension for cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294121/fixed-dimension-for-cordova-app)

Answer (score 0):

Cordova apps are running in fullscreen :) I've been developing with cordova for a while and so far it is impossible to run an app in custom width/height.

[image: cordova custom width&height]

You can do something like this by setting the content width and height in javascript, but the app is still running in fullscreen.

Comment: I think there is some code that will get the device width and height and assign that as the application width and height to fix the app full screen

Answer (score 0):

I`ve never tried, but from the ace doc you can do it.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ace